# Zerto Failover - Win 2012/16 Servers Get Stuck on "Getting Devices Ready"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, vmware-vsphere, disaster-recovery

We are using Zerto to replicate our VMs to an offsite datacenter.  During our failover tests the VMs have a tendency to "hang" from 15 minutes to several hours on "Getting Devices Ready."  I have read the other posts where the VMs never booted up, that is not the case.  These *usually* boot up within an hour, but sometimes it takes longer.

Some of these VMs were converted from a Physical box, others were built as a VM from the start. I am trying to optimize the speed of our failover tests to reduce the amount of time it takes to failover to our DR site using Zerto.  Some online posts have suggested that uninstalling the PnP Monitor has fixed this, but from what I have seen, you can only disable it, not uninstall it.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment:**

- vSPhere 6.5 U1 w/ vCenter
- Zerto 6.5
- Affected VMs - Windows Server 2012 R2 and
  2016 Zerto 6.5

Thanks.